# Discord Slash Message Command Not Working

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I am trying to implement a discord "message slash" command https://discord.com/developers/docs/interactions/application-commands#message-commands

There doesnt seem to be any tutorials showing how to proerpyl use slash command with discord cogs, after a bunch of searching I found this code which does setup a 'CHAT_INPUT' slash command.

```
intents = discord.Intents.all()

client = discord.Client(intents=discord.Intents.all())
slash = SlashCommand(client, sync_commands=True)  # Declares slash commands through the client.

guilds = [id]

@slash.slash(name="pingpong")
async def _ping(ctx):
    await ctx.send("Pong!")

client.run("token")
```

When running the above it does create a slash command, so I can type "/pinppong" but I can not figure out how to make this command appear when I right click on the message. From what I am seeing online need to change the @slash.slash to

```
@slash.slash(name="pingpong", type=3)
```

But this causes the error

```
TypeError: slash() got an unexpected keyword argument 'type'
```

Im not sure what i'm doing wrong here, how can I get the "right click on message" application to work.

Does anyone have any better working examples on how to implement slash commands with discord cogs?

Comment: Which slash command library is this?

Comment: from discord_slash import SlashCommand

Comment: im not sure i understand your question? It is the Discord Slash Commands?

Comment: I ask that question because there are multiple implementations of discord slash commands for python.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, I can try which ever you think would be work. I pip installed this https://pypi.org/project/discord-py-slash-command/

Comment: Uhg, I just stumbled upon https://gist.github.com/Rapptz/4a2f62751b9600a31a0d3c78100287f1/ which opens a can of worms :'( I guess im open to any suggestions

Comment: `discord.py` is no longer maintained, I don't know if their version of slash commands is even compatible with Discord's API.

Comment: You can use a lib like pycord or nextcord which are forks of discord.py and are being maintained atm. Would probably be less of a headache too.

Comment: Do you have any code samples for pycord or nextcord that actually work? I have tried like 3/4 samples for both and nothing works :'( Both of them seem to be on the bleeding edge with slash commands and possible why things are borked

Comment: For example these do not work https://docs.pycord.dev/en/master/quickstart.html